# jQuery UI Droppable - trigger "over" event when element is over itself?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Is it possible to also trigger the "over" event when the element being dragged (it's clone) is still "over" itself? (when the mouse cursor is still within the original element boundaries)?

I need this specific behavior but can't come up with any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The `over` event in jQuery UI will fire repeatedly while dragging an element. You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/yYKmw/12/. If you still want to fire the `over` event while the cursor is within the original element boundaries we can use the [`start`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start) event to fire it initially. This works because when dragging begins the cursor must be within the original element boundaries (How else could the element be dragged?). So that works for the initial drag, but what about if the user moves the element back to its original position? We can track that by attaching the placeholder `.index()` to the `ui.item` (cloned helper) as data during the start event and checking that data on [`change`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-change). To avoid duplicating code we can use jQuery's [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to fire the sortable `over` event.

Code is below and here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yYKmw/11/

### HTML

```
<ul  id="sortable">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
<div id="output">
    <span></span>
</div>
<div id="test"></div>
```

### CSS

```
#sortable { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin: 1em; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 30%; 
    float: left;
}
#sortable li { 
    height: 20px; 
    background-color: khaki;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 2px;
}
.sortable-placeholder {
    background-color: red !important;
}
#output {
    clear:both; 
    border: thin solid black; 
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    color: black;
}
```

### JS

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable({
    placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    start: function(event, ui){
        $('#sortable').trigger('sortover');
        ui.item.data('startIndex', $('#sortable .sortable-placeholder').index());
    },
    change: function(event, ui){
        if ( $('#sortable .sortable-placeholder').index() === ui.item.data('startIndex') ) {
            $('#sortable').trigger('sortover');
        }
    },
    over: function(){
        //do something
        $('#output span').html('over fired').fadeOut(600, function(){
            $('#output span').html('').show()
        })
    }
});
```